# How can I export a SQL Server 2008 database?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-express

Is it possible to export my database that i created in SQL Server 2008 Express?

I'm asking this because I need my group mate to be able to work on the same one. I know you can generate a script for the database but it give a bunch of errors when we try to run it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can right click the dbase then Task->Backup
This will generate a .bak file which you can
Task->Restore to a new database

You can refer here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms187048.aspx

Comment: or connect to a common server via IP

Comment: Im getting an error saying " The database was backed up on a server tunning 10.50.4000. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running 10.00.2531

Comment: ok. looks like you're running SQL 2008 R2 and your friend is running just SQL2008. SQL has no backward compatibility.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. You can export your sqlserver database by using these steps.

1. Right click on your database and hover on Tasks, you got another dropdown, Select Back Up.
2. You got a pop-up like this.
   [image]
3. Click on OK button.
4. Navigate to path on your local PC (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\your database)
5. You got your exported database.

Answer (score 0):

Back it up on disk, give a copy of the file to your friend and tell him to restore a database from that copy.

See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190436.aspx) for more help

Comment: There must be an easier way

Comment: @Sebastian no, I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

Yes,export database from sql server 2008 express is possible..
create backup file and export it.